# Close all panels and update a dynamic p:accordionPanel using p:ajax

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to close all panels and update a **dynamic** PrimeFaces 8 `p:accordionPanel`. I try to close all panels in the `p:ajax onstart` using the widget var. That does close them, but after the update they are opened again. Without `dynamic="true"` it does work (even without the `onstart`). Is this easily fixable in the XHTML, or am I looking at a bug here?

```
<h:form id="main">
  <p:dataTable value="#{appointments.lazy}"
               lazy="true"
               var="appo"
               rowKey="#{appo.id}"
               selectionMode="single"
               selection="#{appointments.selected}"
               rows="10">
    <p:column headerText="#{msg.date}">#{appo.startTime}</p:column>
    <p:ajax event="rowSelect"
            onstart="var a=PF('acc');for(i=0;i&lt;a.panels.length;i++){a.unselect(i)}"
            update="main:acc"/>
  </p:dataTable>

  <p:accordionPanel id="acc"
                    widgetVar="acc"
                    dynamic="true"
                    multiple="true"
                    activeIndex="">
    <p:tab title="#{now}">#{now}</p:tab>
    <p:tab title="#{now}">#{now}</p:tab>
  </p:accordionPanel>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using a listener on my `p:ajax` to reset the active indexes:

```
public void resetActivePanels() {
  org.omnifaces.util.Components
    .findComponentsInCurrentForm(AccordionPanel.class)
    .get(0)
    .setActiveIndex("");
}
```

This also eliminates the need to close each panel first on start:

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect"
        listener="#{appointments.resetActivePanels()}"
        update="main:acc"/>
```